# Some Really Confusing Math

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, no-computers, formation-of-numbers

I was talking to a co-worker this morning and he stated that he was able to make both of these statements true using only $1, 3, 5,$ or $ 7$. He then proceeded to tell me:

- $1 = 5$
- $2 = 4 + 7$
- $3 = 1$
- $4 = 5$
- $5 = 6 - 3$
- $6 = 4$
- $7 = 5 + 1$
- $8 = 2 - 3 + 5$

---

While solving for $x$ and $y$ make both statements true.

> Solve for $x$.
>   $$x = \frac{1 \cdot 3}{7 + 3^7} + 2y^2$$
>   Solve for $y$.
>   $$y = 4x^3 - 5x^2 + 6x^1 - 8$$

Comment: Hey! Congrats on 3,000! :D keep up the good puzzles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure this is how this is supposed to be solved but this is what I did. 
For x:

> $x = \frac{1\cdot3}{7+3^7} +2y^2$ 
>  $x = \frac{5\cdot1}{(5+1)+1^7} +(4+7)y^2$ 
>  $x = \frac{5}{((6-3)+1)+1} +(5+5+1)y^2$ 
>  $x = \frac{5}{5} +((6-3)+(6-3)+1)y^2$ 
>  $x = 1 +((4-1)+(4-1)+1)y^2$  
>  $x = 1 +((5-5)+(5-5)+1)y^2$ 
>  $x = 1 +1y^2$ 
>  Finally turn the $y^2$ to a y by changing the 2 to 1 by the same process that the coefficient of y was turned from a 2 to a 1 giving you :  $x = 1+y$

For y:

> $y = 4x^3-5x^2+6x^1-8$ 
>  $y = 4x^1 +6x^1-(6-3)x^2 -(2-3+5)$ 
>  $y = 4x^1 +4x^1-(4-3)x^2 -(2-3+(6-3))$ 
>  $y = 8x-(5-3)x^2 -(8-6))$ 
>  $y = 2x-3x+5x-((6-3)-3)x^2 -(2-3+5-6))$ 
>  $y = 2x-x+6x-3x-0x^2 -(4-6))$ 
>  $y = 4x-(5-6))$ 
>  $y = 5x-(6-3-6))$ 
>  $y = 6x-3x-(6-3-4))$ 
>  $y =3x-(6-1-4))$  
>  $y =1x-(1))$ 
>  which has equality with $x = y +1$